# Custom methods for push notifications using UrbanAirship iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm working on an iOS app which receives a push notification from a custom API written in Java which should prompt the user to either acccept or reject a petition to join a table. I'm working on an existing code-base written a while back and updating the software.

The problem is, that it seems that UrbanAirship has radically modified their behaviors and I'm no longer able to present our custom notification boxes.

The notifications being sent by our API are structed as follows:

```
[Line 227] Received notification: {
    "_" = "4f5a2ac1-f337-4181-9c88-70b65d4f501f";
    aps =     {
        alert = "Tu mesa ya est\U00e1 abierta";
    };
    command = 1;
    mode = createCommand;
    posType = 2;
    restaurant = "Zadia Restaurant";
    restaurantId = 1;
}
```

And we have the following methods implemented in our AppDelegate : UAPushNotificationDelegate (I'm only including the code relevant to UAirship for the sake of brevety:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if !application.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() { //En caso de que no tengamos permisos para push notifications
        showWarningDialog()
    } else {
        UAirship.takeOff()
        UAirship.push().userNotificationTypes = ([UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound])
        UAirship.push().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true
        UAirship.push().pushNotificationDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}

func receivedForegroundNotification(notification: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)) {

    if OurApp.sharedInstance.isCommandTopViewController && notification["type"] != nil && (notification["type"] as! String) == "updateCommand" {
        OurApp.sharedInstance.commandController?.refresh()
    }

    if notification["type"] != nil {

        if (notification["type"] as! String).contains("joinRequest") {
            showJoinRequestDialog(notification["aps"]!["alert"] as! String, userId: notification["userId"] as! Int)
        } else if (notification["type"] as! String).contains("joinResponse") {

            let state = notification["state"] as! Int

            if state == 1 {
                self.preferenceManager.saveCurrentTab(notification["command"] as? String)
                self.preferenceManager.saveCurrentRestaurant(notification["restaurant"] as? String)
            }

            showJoinResponseDialog(notification["aps"]!["alert"] as! String, state: state)

        } else if (notification["type"] as! String).contains("promotion") {
            showNewPromotionDialog(notification["aps"]!["alert"] as! String, promotion: notification["promotionId"] as! Int)
        }
    }

    // Call the completion handler
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
}

func launchedFromNotification(notification: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)) {

    if notification["type"] != nil {

        if (notification["type"] as! String).contains("joinRequest") {
            showJoinRequestDialog(notification["aps"]!["alert"] as! String, userId: notification["userId"] as! Int)
        } else if (notification["type"] as! String).contains("joinResponse") {

            let state = notification["state"] as! Int

            if state == 1 {
                self.preferenceManager.saveCurrentTab(notification["command"] as? String)
                self.preferenceManager.saveCurrentRestaurant(notification["restaurant"] as? String)
            }

            showJoinResponseDialog(notification["aps"]!["alert"] as! String, state: state)
        }
    }

    // Call the completion handler
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
}

func showJoinRequestDialog(message: String, userId: Int) {

    let dialog: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Atención", comment:""), message: message + NSLocalizedString("¿Quieres aceptarlo?", comment:""), preferredStyle: .Alert)

    dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Aceptar", comment:""), style: .Default, handler: { action in

        let state = 1

        self.sendAcceptRequest(userId, state: state)
        dialog.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Rechazar", comment:""), style: .Cancel, handler: { action in

        let state = 0

        self.sendAcceptRequest(userId, state: state)
        dialog.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showJoinResponseDialog(message: String, state: Int) {

    let dialog: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Atención", comment:""), message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Aceptar", comment:""), style: .Default, handler: { action in

        if state == 1 {
            let mainViewController = OurApp.sharedInstance.mainController
            mainViewController.navigateOnSideMenu("command")
        }

        dialog.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showNewPromotionDialog(message: String, promotion: Int) {

    let dialog: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Atención", comment:""), message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    dialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Aceptar", comment:""), style: .Default, handler: { action in

        let mainViewController = OurApp.sharedInstance.mainController

        mainViewController.navigateOnSideMenu("promotions")
        dialog.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(dialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sendAcceptRequest(userId: Int, state: Int) {}
```

If anyone could lend a helping hand to, at least, point me in the right direction in regards to updating the code to work correctly with the new versions of the Urban Airship SDK and iOS 11, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is "type" in your notification payload? Seems like this will return nil: notification["type"]

Comment: I can modify the notification to fit the needs of SDK, but the issue is a bit deeper I feel. If I eliminate all of the custom code and send a notification from tue website to all ios devices, I get the notification on the device. So good so far, but then, I haven’t been able to figure out how I interact with the buttons that are shown in the notification beyond the few options that the website provides. So if someone could provide a simple example where one can interact with the accept/decline buttons and run a custom method for those; that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to override [receivedNotificationResponse](https://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Protocols/UAPushNotificationDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)UAPushNotificationDelegate(im)receivedNotificationResponse:completionHandler:) instead of foreground notification. You will then have access to notification, user response, and button action ID.

Comment: Thanks; does this mean that I should remove the receivedForegroundNotification function completely, or can I just leave it there?